# Using while loop in array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli

Trying to generate maximum and minimum time duration by putting values from mysql query to array and then calculating time duration.

I don't know how to run query in array. Please help.

Here is my exact code:

```
$mindur_query = mysql_query("SELECT *, CONCAT(`cancel_date`, `pur_date`) AS orderdate FROM `sales_report` WHERE $cancelled_query $req_query $req_status CONCAT(`cancel_date`, `pur_date`) BETWEEN '$req_date1' AND '$req_date2' ORDER BY orderdate"); 
while($mindur_fetch = mysql_fetch_array($mindur_query)){
$mindurtermi_date = $mindur_fetch['termi_date'];
$mindurstr_date = $mindur_fetch['str_date'];

$diff = (strtotime($mindurtermi_date)- strtotime($mindurstr_date))/24/3600; 
$total_diff = number_format($diff, 0); // Want to put this value in array
}
```

I want array like this:
$array = array($total_diff); //All values of $total_diff

Comment: RTFM? [datediff()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) and [timediff()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff)

Comment: That topic is totally off-topic!

Comment: @developerwjk: it's not an infinite loop. it'll just fetch rows of query results until there's no more rows to fetch.

Comment: Ok, maybe `mysql_fetch_array` does only fetch one row after all.  Its been a while since I've used the deprecated `mysql_` functions, so give me a break.

Comment: The question is totally unclear then. If its not that this is causing an infinite loop, what's the problem?

Comment: I just want to put all values of $total_diff into an array

Comment: mysql query is just to get dates and the main thing is duration calculation which is calculating with this code: $diff = (strtotime($mindurtermi_date)- strtotime($mindurstr_date))/24/3600;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do this:

```
$total_diff[] = number_format($diff, 0);
```

Comment: I want to put all values of $total_diff into an array how can I do that ?

Comment: Thats exactly what I wrote. The '[]' notation declares $ total_diff as an array hence it will keep on appending new values to the array as it loops.... you can access the first value using $ total_diff [0]

Comment: Thanks a lot its working for me. You understand my question very well